# Alphabetizing a list of hash keys in perl?

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, alphabetical

I want to make an array that stores an alphabetized list of hash keys. I tried this method:

```
@sorted = sort { $hash{$a} cmp $hash{$b} } keys %hash;
```

...But it turns out this returns a list of hash keys sorted by value (whereas I want a list of hash keys sorted alphabetically).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
my @sorted = sort { $a cmp $b } keys %hash;
```

or just

```
my @sorted = sort keys %hash;
```

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for showing me both ways, it helps conceptually to see how easy the expression simplifies

Answer (score 3):

Hash keys are just strings:

```
@sorted = sort keys %hash;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach my $key ( sort {$a cmp $b} keys %hash) {

# do something ..

}
```